# Password encryption Codeigniter

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to make my login form to work but no luck so far. I need to use the encrypt class in order to retrieve the password later at my edit form. I already tested the encode and decode seem to work fine but I just cannot login. When I tested it with the md5 function I could login properly so the problem must be somewhere in the model. Please any ideas?

```
function validate(){
$this->db->from('users')->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
$query = $this->db->get();
$rows = $query->row();
$password = $this->input->post('password');
 if($query->num_rows == 1){
if ($this->encrypt->decode($rows->password) === $password ) {
return true;
}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if ($this->encrypt->decode($rows->password) === $password )`  to `if ($this->encrypt->decode($rows->password) == $password ) {` `===` checks whether the objects are of the same type i.e. arrays, null.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
$password = md5($this->input->post('password')); // for encrypting the password
```